# Not able to create Spring Roo project in STS 3.7.2 Release

Tags: java, spring-roo, spring-tool-suite

I am not able to create Spring Roo project in Spring Tool Suite 3.7.2 release even though I installed Spring Roo plugin from the marketplace. When I go to create project using New- Spring Roo Project, Nothing pops up when I hit Next button.

Comment: Have you checked log files in `workspace/.metadata/.log` or `eclipse/configuration/*.log`?

Comment: Please describe your environment: STS, Java, Roo, addons, etc.

Comment: As @eruiz ask you... could you provide more info about your environment? Which version of the Spring Roo project are you using? Which Java version are you using?... We always recommend to use the lastest version of STS if you are using the lastest version of the Spring Roo project.